# How to update only a subset of fields and update the repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, postman

I'm making a spring boot application, and I'm looking to update an existing entry in the DB through my service and controller. In my service layer I have the below method. So I'm retrieving the fields associated with a caseID, creating a model mapper which maps my entity object class to my VO, and then mapping the retrieved data to my DTO. Then I save my repository. The purpose is to add only the fields which I have specified in my req message ie if I only want to update 1 field out of 20, it updates this field and leaves the rest untouched. The below runs successfully, but the field I specify in my request message in postman does not update in the DB. Why is this? I have tried mapping different objects and saving different variables to the repository but nothing seems to update the DB.

```
public StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO updateCase(OutboundErrorCaseVO outboundErrorCaseVO, Long caseNumber) {
    OutboundErrorCaseData existingCaseData = ErrorCaseDataRepository.findById(caseNumber).get();
    ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
    mm.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(true);
    OutboundErrorCaseData uiOutboundErrorCaseData = mm.map(outboundErrorCaseVO,
            OutboundErrorCaseData.class);
    mm.map(existingCaseData, uiOutboundErrorCaseData);
    ErrorCaseDataRepository.save(uiOutboundErrorCaseData);
    return mm.map(uiOutboundErrorCaseData, StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO.class);
}
```

Controller - code omitted for brevity, POST method (I usually use PUT for updates but I believe I can still use POST)

```
    StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO updatedCase = outboundErrorService.updateCase(outboundErrorCaseVO,
            caseNumber);
```

Repo

```
    @Repository
public interface OutboundErrorCaseDataRepository extends JpaRepository<OutboundErrorCaseData, Long> {
```

Comment: Are you using `spring-data` JpaRepository? If no, then share implementation of `ErrorCaseDataRepository.save()`

Comment: You also seem not to be following Java code conventions (specifically variable naming), which makes this difficult to follow.

Comment: Are you using your repository statically?  It should be a bean that you wire into your service

Comment: Yes, repo is autowired into service. I've edited to show impl

Comment: Can you tell me the value of existingCaseData.getId() ( or whaterver is the getter method for your entity Id) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working solution, although I realise it can be improved, it certainly works. The only drawback is that I need to specify all the fields which can be updated, ideally I want a solution which takes in n number of fields and updates the record.

```
OutboundErrorCaseData existingCaseDta = ErrorCaseDataRepository.findById(caseNumber).get();
    if (outboundErrorCaseVO.getChannel() != null) {
        existingCaseDta.setChannel(outboundErrorCaseVO.getChannel());
    }
ErrorCaseDataRepository.save(existingCaseDta);
    ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
    return mm.map(existingCaseDta, StoredOutboundErrorCaseVO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data and passing it into `existingCaseData` and save `uiOutboundErrorCaseData`. So my guess is Hibernate is adding a new object into the database with new Id and with you updated value. It of course depends on your model definition. Especially `id`.

I also think Hibernate won't let you save `uiOutboundErrorCaseData` with the same Id if you already have an object in Hibernate Session associated with that id. So, why don't you update `existingCaseData` with the new value and save it back.